# How do I remove the iPhone KeyBoard toolbar border?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code to remove the toolbar from the iPhone keyboard when it is displayed.

```
- (void) keyboardDidShowNotification:(NSNotification *)aNotification {

NSArray *array = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows];

for (UIWindow* wind in array) {
    for (UIView* currView in wind.subviews) {
        if ([[currView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIPeripheralHostView"]) {
            for (UIView* perView in currView.subviews) {
                if ([[perView description] hasPrefix:@"<UIWebFormAccessory"]) {
                    [perView removeFromSuperview];
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

}

This is removing the toolbar like I want but it is still leaving a 1px border above where the toolbar use to be. How do I remove that as well?

Also this only appears to be an issue on iPhone Retina displays. iPhone 3GS and iPad Retina do not have it.

Comment: This is a really nasty way of doing this. Can't you access the keyboard's accessory view directly by calling, for example, UITextField's `inputAccessoryView` method and setting it to nil?

Comment: No have to do it this way since I am using a UIWebView.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a bug in removeFromSuperView.  I had the same problem when adding a toolbar as an input accessory view to some pickers for inline editing.  Calling 2x removeFromSuperView left the border.
Using [self.view endEditing:YES] when closing the picker helped to clean up the picker and the accessory view attached to it, with no border.  Perhaps this can point you into the right direction?